# Treat Null as Max

Tags: sql, null, max

So if I had a table in my database with the values

```
1
2
3
4
NULL
```

And I executed the query

```
SELECT MAX(col1) FROM <table>
```

I'd get 4. Is there any way to change this so Null would be treated as the maximum as oppose to the minimum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(col1, 2147483647)) FROM <table>
```

[2147483647 = 2^31  - 1]

Comment: I can get that to work in my code, but that will actuall be returning 2147483647 if there is a null present, any way to get null?

Comment: Just add a `if` statement around the `MAX(..` statement, turning 2147483647  back into null

Comment: Of course! I'm blaming that second question on it being friday! 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just as a variant, you can do this on Oracle.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT col1 
           FROM <table>
          ORDER BY col1 DESC NULLS FIRST
       )
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

(OP hasn't specified any particular flavour of database)

Comment: Doh, as the others guessed it was MSSql but I'm sure this will help futures

Answer (score 1):

```
      SELECT MAX(ISNULL(col1, YouBiggestNumber)) FROM <table>
```